# Error when passing URL from environment.ts to iFrame in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I have a page with iFrame inside, and I am trying to pass an URL to it from my environemnt.ts
So my TS file looks as below:

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
...
export class IframePage {
constructor(
...
)
public IFRAME_URL: string = environment.externalUrl.myUrl + 'someDetails';
}
```

And in my HTML file, it looks like:

```
<iframe
  [src]="IFRAME_URL"
  style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 90vh; top: 0"
  >iFrame not working!</iframe
>
```

After doing all this, I get an error:  `[SYSTEM_ERROR] unsafe value used in a resource URL context`
I've tried to find a solution from the existing questions, but nothing worked as for now. Sorry for a noob question, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to sanitize the URL and let Angular know that the URL is safe. Try the following

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class IframePage implements OnInit {
  public IFRAME_URL: string;

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.IFRAME_URL = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(environment.externalUrl.myUrl + 'someDetails');
  }
}
```

From [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#security-risk) docs:

> Calling any of the `bypassSecurityTrust...` APIs disables Angular's
>   built-in sanitization for the value passed in. Carefully check and
>   audit all values and code paths going into this call. Make sure any
>   user data is appropriately escaped for this security context.

It is advisable to take precautions while passing URLs to the sanitizer. As the documentation suggests, it disables Angular's built-in sanitization.